# get AJAX Collect Endpoint of product

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, screen-scraping

I've been trying to find an API for this website but have not yet to find something. I however did found some AJAX data, but I do not know a lot about ajax and how to put it together to get a working product data endpoint url. Up untill now I have found this data:

```
Product URL:
https://www.gamemania.nl/nl/consoles/xbox-one/136179_xbox-one-s-white-1tb

Request URL (POST):
https://www.gamemania.nl/index.cfm/product/ajax/collect

Form Data (SOURCE): action=collect&skuId=10509132&qty=1&sPostalcode=&sLat=&sLong=&productId=5518085&preorder=false&preorderStock=0&combined=false&showWithoutStock=true

Form Data (PARSED):
action: collect
skuId: 10509132
qty: 1
sPostalcode: 
sLat: 
sLong: 
productId: 5518085
preorder: false
preorderStock: 0
combined: false
showWithoutStock: true
```

I want to know if i can turn this into a good URL which i can then scrape data from, or if this will not be possible.

Big thanks in advance! :)

Comment: are you trying to guess their apis or you have a documentation

Comment: @flakerimi I'm trying to find a hidden API to efficiently scrape the items stock

Comment: Its not possible, also wrong/illegal. Scrape from front.